# Eclipse Package Explorer and Visual Studio Solution Explorer difference

Tags: eclipse

When I programmed in Visual Studio, I used to open a Solution, then Solution Explorer showed me only projects contained in that Solution.
When I work in Eclipse, instead, Package Explorer always shows to me all the projects into workspace, which, often, is not what I want.

Is it normal? Or should it appear like Visual Studio? In the latter case how can I achieve it? Should I treat Eclipse Workspace the same as Visual Studio Solution? (e.g. one workspace for each multi-library project).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, by default the Packages View shows everything.

You can change the view to arrange the top level by [Working Set](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fcworkset.htm) to split up the view.

You can also use Eclipse [Mylyn](http://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/start/) to arrange things by task (Mylyn is included in some Eclipse downloads or can be installed separately).